# can i use multiple times (input/output)stream for different types of data transfer between two nodes

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

In this code I use multiple times of retrieve input-output data from two nodes. ... when I use more than two times input output stream it generated this type of error while running this code I need different input and output and that I want to store but unfortunate if I used more than three-time  input/output stream it show error

---

```
   public class Server {
private static Socket socket;
public void connect() throws IOException{
        int port = 25000;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");
 socket = serverSocket.accept();
}
        //Server is running always. This is done using this while(true) loop

            //Reading the message from the client
  public void first() throws IOException{      
      connect();
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String number = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from client is "+number);

            //Multiplying the number by 2 and forming the return message
            String returnMessage;
            try
            {
                int numberInIntFormat = Integer.parseInt(number);
                int returnValue = numberInIntFormat*2;
                returnMessage = String.valueOf(returnValue) + "\n";
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                //Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to   

          client.
                returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
            }
            second();
            String e=br.readLine();System.out.println(e);
      }

       public void second() throws IOException{
            //Sending the response back to the client.
      String returnMessage="Second";
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write(returnMessage);
            System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returnMessage);
            bw.flush();
        }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    Server obj = new Server();

    obj.first();
   // obj.second();

           }public class Server {
  private static Socket socket;
     public void connect() throws IOException{
        int port = 25000;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");
  socket = serverSocket.accept();
   }
        //Server is running always. This is done using this while(true) loop

            //Reading the message from the client
   public void first() throws IOException{      
      connect();
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String number = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from client is "+number);

            //Multiplying the number by 2 and forming the return message
            String returnMessage;
            try
            {
                int numberInIntFormat = Integer.parseInt(number);
                int returnValue = numberInIntFormat*2;
                returnMessage = String.valueOf(returnValue) + "\n";
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                //Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to client.
                returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
            }
            second();
            String e=br.readLine();System.out.println(e);
      }

      public void second() throws IOException{
            //Sending the response back to the client.
      String returnMessage="Second";
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write(returnMessage);
            System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returnMessage);
            bw.flush();
        }

       public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

       Server obj = new Server();

       obj.first();
   // obj.second();

    }
```

---

```
           public class client {

       private static Socket socket;

    //public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{



   //}
    public void first() throws IOException{
   String host = "localhost";
        int port = 25000;
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        socket = new Socket(address, port);

     OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        String number = "2";

        String sendMessage = number + "\n";
        bw.write(sendMessage);
        bw.flush();
        System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);
     String sendMessage1="3333";
    bw.write(sendMessage1);
     bw.flush();
    //second();

        }


        public void second1() throws IOException{

     //Get the return message from the server
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr;
       isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String message = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
    socket.close();
  }
  public static void main (String argd[]) throws IOException{

    client obj1 = new client();
    obj1.first();




    }
    -----------------------------------------

          error

          Message received from client is 2
            Message sent to the client is Second
      Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
```

---

---

Comment: No, you can't use multiple input/output streams, once they have been obtained for a given socket. Could you please provide the exception/error details too in the question BTW?

Comment: Your question has nothing whatsoever to do with RMI. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream` and `OutputStream` are intended to work with a single source and destination. Once you obtain an `InputStream` that reads from file/socket/whatever source you can use it for multiple consecutive reads. But once you are done reading from that source you need to invoke `close()` method on your stream.

Not closing your stream is classic reason for a memory leak in Java. In fact for that reason you ALWAYS expected to surround the usage of your source with try catch and always invoke `close()` method in finally statement. So to insure that it is always invoked. Further more, since `close()` method itself can cause an `Exception`, within final statement you need to surround it with its own try-catch. Starting from java 7 there is a new feature called "try with resources" that deals with this particular issue.

Please read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)